# Get error in Power Apps when I'm using an if statement

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am new to power app development and can't figure out why my code is not working.

```
If(!IsBlank(personal_data.Selected.Value) || !IsBlank(public.Selected.Value), Reset(loss_in_revenue);
```

The code is supposed to just query in a button if something from the radio-buttons
`personal_data` or `public"` was selected.
If yes, it should reset "loss_in_revenue".

Power Apps has shown me that error: unexpected sign. The formula contains "error", but "ParenClose" is expected.

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indenting the formula will help show the error:

```
If(
    !IsBlank(personal_data.Selected.Value) || !IsBlank(public.Selected.Value),
    Reset(loss_in_revenue);
```

See that the `(` that is opening the `If` call is not being closed. Closing it should solve this error:

```
If(
    !IsBlank(personal_data.Selected.Value) || !IsBlank(public.Selected.Value),
    Reset(loss_in_revenue)
)
```